# Link Templates for wiki entries

Tags: discussion

Aloks post about ['Game card' like template for tag wiki?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5217/game-card-like-template-for-tag-wiki) made me think that it would be good to have a standardized Links section on every game wiki entry.

Why do we need this?

Currently every wiki page has its own structure. While this is good, some of them just describe the game and do not point the reader to other sites for this game. We as a community can filter and list good sites for a particular game.

If I am on a QA site like Arqade and look at a game in more detail I want the following questions answered:

- What is the official game site?
- Where can I find a good review of the game?
- Where can I find a comprehensive list of all the cheats of the game that actually work.
- Where can I find a good Walkthrough of the game, so I do not miss any Achievements or goodies?
- I want to get more in depth information about the game. Where do I start?
- What are good community sites for this game?

It is not the job of Arqade to provide the actual information on everything game related, but we should give pointers.

Sure I could go to the chat, but many people shy away from chats because of various reasons:

- They cannot type fast enough
- They are not fluent in English and have trouble understand everything, especially with IRC acronyms
- There might be no one currently in the chat that plays this game and it is stupid to ask the same question every 30 minutes or so.

Or I could ask a question on Arqade, but guess what happens if I post something like this:

- "Can you point me to good sites for X?"

It gets closed immediately.

So I am proposing a Link template. It could look like this:

**Links:**

About the game:

- [Official Site](http://example.com/)
- [Review](http://example.com/some_review_site)
- [Trailer](http://trailer.example.com/some_trailer)

Community Sites:

- [Wiki](http://example.com/wiki) - The currently most comprehensive Wiki for the game
- [Forum](http://example.com/fan_forum) - Clan site of Team Y with a moderated forum
- [German Forum](http://example.com/german) - A good German source for Z
- IRC Channel: Server: Quakenet, Channel: #some_game

Cheats / Walkthrough:

- [Cheats](http://example.com/cheats) - Some Tips and Cheats for the Single Player
- [Walkthrough](http://example.com/walkthrough) - A good Walkthrough of the game

For Starcraft 2 it might look like this:

**Links:**

About the game:

- [Official Site](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/)
- [Review](http://www.gamespot.com/starcraft-ii-wings-of-liberty/)
- [Trailer](http://www.gamestar.de/index.cfm?pid=1589&pk=9418)

Community Sites:

- [Wiki](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Main_Page) - A Wiki with lots of information. It is not always up to date.
- [Forum](http://www.teamliquid.net/) - Clan site of Team Teamliquid with a moderated forum
- [German Forum](http://starcraft2.ingame.de/index.php) - German forum with lots of guides
- IRC Channel: Server: irc.quakenet.org, Channel: #teamliquid - Official chat channel of Teamliquid

Cheats / Walkthrough:

- [Cheats](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/starcraft2cheatscodes.html#.UB0tgU0ge50) - Some Tips and Cheats for the Single Player
- [Walkthrough](http://www.gamespot.com/features/starcraft-2-wings-of-liberty-walkthrough-6272636/) - A Walkthrough of the game with many Screenshots

The links might not be the best ones, but you get the idea.

Some Games might not have a big community, but I think that the structure should still be provided, even if it is empty:

**Links:**

About the game:

Community Sites:

Cheats / Walkthrough:

A user that asks a subjective question or some kind of list question can be directed to the wiki entry, so he can use these sources instead.

Comment: Linking one specific review is likely to be biased. It's probably better form to link somewhere where reviews are aggregated. Other than that, though, this is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Be bold! Start improving the tag wiki for the tags in page one of our top tags list and propose the edits. You'll even get some reputation per accepted edit!